# UDP communication through proxy

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding, udp

I have following scenario:

[image: Network scenario: PC B (TCP/IP,SOCKS5)-> PC A (TCP/IP)-> ISP router]

PC B must be capable of full TCP/UPD connectivity, so I'm testing scenario with typical FPS game.

ProxyCap is proxifier software, that can connect to outside world pretty well. The problem is, that UDP responses from server are not coming through PC A to PC B. I guess problem is in port forwarding. Proxy cannot forward anything, right?

One solution that have occurred to me is to forward every UPD packet to PC B. Why not? PC B would accept only on ports he listens on and it's not probable, that it would listen on same ports as PC A, isn't it? Is there such possibility? What software would i need to use? Please note, that I'm on Windows platform.

*Note: NAT is really not an option, since it reveals presence of PC B (NAT can be easily discovered). I really want the communication to look like it have been sent by PC A.*

Answer (score 1):

First, I would not recommend forwarding all UDP traffic to the interior host.

your issue appears to be the stateless-ness of UDP traffic. There is no such thing as a request or a response in UDP protocols, just streams passing in whatever direction. for this reason, someone could inject bad traffic into your stream if you just route all UDP inbound to PC B, or use it to unmask your hidden network.

My guess is that the problem is the proxy between your host and the NAT wall. NAT can't use connection orientation to map UDP flows together, so it doesn't have a solid idea of what signals are desired and which aren't. most routers use a combination of port numbers and timing to determine if it is likely that two flows are related so nat can allow inbound streams only when they *appear* to be solicited, but usually you have to allow udp services in your firewall port by port to ensure that you get all the segments.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a SOCKS5 proxy to tunnel TCP/UDP packets. If you are using HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS4 you will not be able to set up ProxyCap to proxy UDP packets as SOCKS5 is the only one that supports UDP.

Comment: ProxyCap is indeed set to be SOCKS5. Proxy is also forced to use SOCKS5. Problem is, i'm not getting response from server.